# Reading a numerical data file and assigning to each items at the same time

Tags: python

I am a beginner in python, and I have a problem when I want to read my numeric data file that contains more lines. My data in the input file contains rows that include a counter number, three float numbers, and finally, a character letter that all of them separated by space.it look like this:

```
                 1  12344567.143   12345678.154  1234.123   w   
                 2  23456789.231   23413456.342  4321.321   f
```

I want to assign each item in the line to a specific parameter that I can use them to other steps.
like this    "NO"=first item   "X"=second item   "Y"=third item  "code"=forth item
I am trying to write it as follow:

```
f1=open('t1.txt','r')
line: float
for line in f1:
print(line.split(', ',4))
f1=float
select(line.split('')
nob: object(1)=int(line[1, 1])
cnt = 0
print(nob)
cnt +=1
```

but received more error each time when I run the program. Anyone can help me?

Comment: can you add an expected output

Comment: And please fix indentations as they are a critical part in understanding Python code

Comment: A file that I want for output as is below:
first-line = X variable ( second Item of the first line)
#second line is blank
#third line is blank
fourth line = Y variable ( third item of the first line)
#fifth line is blank 
#sixth line is blank
seventh line = Z variable ( fourth item of the first line)
and it repeats for the second line of my data file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is probably due to the wrong indentation: in Python indentation is part of the syntax. It would be helpful if you also included the error message in your question.

How about this:

```
all_first_numbers = []
with open('t1.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        values = line.split()
        first_number = int(values[0])
        second_number = float(values[1])
        letter_code = values[4]
        # If you want to save all the first numbers in one array:
        all_first_numbers.append(first_number)
```